# concerns about adding a new index over a big table

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, alter-table, mysql-5.7

I have a table with 100± millions rows.  During a day over one million new rows are inserted.

I want to add a new index on a string column.

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME` ADD INDEX `INDEX_NAME`(`COLUMN_NAME`), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

I have a few concerns because this will happen on production:

1. Can indexing lock the table? (even though I specified the `LOCK=NONE` maybe there is an edge case?)
2. Considering that a large amount of rows will be inserted into the table during the indexing, what unexpected situations should I take into consideration?
3. Estimation time for indexing?

Comment: You can have a dump of production of data on any other environment and create your index there first and analyse the result. I think its very tough to analyse specially when data is consistently getting added that too 1M+ rows per day.

Comment: Coincidentally, yesterday I started an `ALTER TABLE` process to change one of my table column from `varchar` to `bigint`. The table have about 200+ million rows and the process is still running. I checked and it has run for 82477 seconds equivalent to 22+ hours. Fortunately this table is not being populated now; which I have control over but I have no clue when will it complete.